# If p is the probability that the 100th passenger sits in his assigned seat, then what's $p^2+(1−p)^2$?

Tags: probability, induction

I was not able to solve this question on my test.

> An aeroplane has $100$ seats (numbered $1$ to $100$) and $100$ passengers waiting to board each having a ticket with a number from $1$ to $100$. No number is on $2$ tickets or on $2$ seats. The rules of boarding are as below:
>
> (i) Passengers board in the order of the number on their respective ticket.
> (ii) The first passenger to board can sit on any seat.
> (iii) A passenger with ticket number $i(i\ne 1)$, boards the plane and sits on seat number '$i$' if it is empty. However, if that seat is occupied he can sit on any empty seat.
>
> If $p$ is the probability that the $100^{th}$ passenger sits in his assigned seat, then $p^2+ (1 - p)^2$ is equal to

So I contacted my teacher and he said to let no. of persons in plane be $n$ and put $n=2,3,4...$ and so on,  use induction, and I will see that it does not depend on $n$ and is constant $=0.5$.  This is the 1st problem I have encountered of this type. Isn't there any other good method to solve it?

Comment: Don't upload image of the question you want to ask rather take effort to type the question as you take to solve the problem because search engines find it difficult to search for images than text. Also, person with weak eyesight can't read it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction is easiest. But you can do a bit of logic.

If passenger $1$ takes the seat of another passenger it is a seat assigned to someone with a number higher then his, say $n_1$.  Then all the passengers between $1$ and $n_1$ will take there seats.  Passenger $n_1$ will enter and find her seat taken.  She has two options: Take passenger $1$s seat, or take the seat of a person higher than hers.

If she takes passenger $1$s seat..... then it's over.  All the rest of the passengers will will have find their seats available.  If the takes a seat of someone higher. Say $n_2$ then all the passengers between $n_1$ and $n_2$ will take their seat and passenger $n_2$ will have the same choice and so on.

Now every time a displaced passenger $n_k$ enters and finds their seat taken there will be to following seats to choose from:  Seat assigned to passenger $1$. .... Seats assigned to passengers: $n_k+1$ through $99$ and seat assigned to passenger $100$.  Whichever seat they choose is equally likely.

Now eventually someone will choose either seat Pass. $1$ and end this. Or choose seat Pass. $100$ and displace passenger $100$.  Given those two options each are equally likely.  It's a matter as to whether a displaced person will choose p$1$ first or p$100$ first.  And neither is weighted more or less than the other.

So the probability is $\frac 12$.

Comment: +1 this was the method which i was looking for

Comment: Your last paragraph said eventually someone will choose either the 1st or the 100th seat... I don't agree, because there's probably someone who choose the 100th seat when there are many seats left, so that's the case you didn't consider.

Comment: @seayellow "so that's the case you didn't consider"  But that's a case were seat #100 was selected before seat #1.  I *did* consider that.  There are two cases:  Case 1:  Seat #1 is chosen before seat #100.  or Case 2: Seat #100 is chosen before seat #1.  I never said *anything* about how many seats are remaining at that time Case 1 or Case 2 happens because that doesn't matter.  If Seat #1 is chosen before seat #100 then passenger #100 gets his seat. If Seat #100 is choose before seat #1 then he doesn't.  That there are almost certainly many seats left doesn't matter.